# Rails says I have x pending migrations Run `rake db:migrate`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In database.yml in my mountable_engine/test/dummy/config, I specify one database for dummy app and one for mountable engine:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: dummy_development

internal:
  <<: *default
  database: mountable_engine_development
```

Now I have migrations in mountable_engine/db/migrate that are specific to the mountable engine database. In fact, the schema.rb file doesn't even exist. Also, in my dummy app my schema.rb file is empty because I have no migrations for it.

I want to load the mountable_engine database with random data. In mountable_engine/lib/tasks/seeds.rake, I have the following task:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :random => :environment do
    task :load do
      CountyProxy.load!
    end
  end
end
```

When I run

```
rake db:random:load RAILS_ENV=internal
```

from the command line, I get the following error:

```
You have 12 pending migrations:
  20150406190542 CreateTable1
  20150406201954 CreateTable2
  20150406202157 CreateTable3
  ...
  20150430225339 AddIndexToForeignKeys
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

I had already run the migrations before. Now when I look at the schema_migrations in the mountable_engine_development database, I can see that the migrations are up to date:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM schema_migrations;
+----------------+
| version        |
+----------------+
| 20150406190542 |
| 20150406201954 |
| 20150406202157 |
| 20150406202339 |
| 20150406202535 |
| 20150406202550 |
| 20150408194521 |
| 20150411010854 |
| 20150413162723 |
| 20150413213522 |
| 20150416013325 |
| 20150430225339 |
+----------------+
```

So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I was running the rake task in the directory of the mountable engine. When I ran the rake task in the directory of the dummy app, then it worked.